# Adding columns from two different files using python

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to add corresponding columns from different text files, however I only get the data from last file. For example I have two files name file1 and file2.I want to add column1 of file1 with column1 of file2 and so on.

```
[for atom in range(1, 3):
    file = open("filename" + str(atom), "r")
    line = file.split("\n")\[0\]
    col1 = float(line.split()\[1\])
    col2 = float(line.split()\[2\])
    col3 = float(line.split()\[3\])
    total = col1 + col2 + col3
file.close()][1]
```

I tried to do col1 += col1 and so on but it did not give the correct value as it does the cumulative sum. I have attached screen shot of the file as well.all files have the same format.

Comment: You are just opening one file at a time, So you wont be able to do whatever you want. You should open both files at the same time then manipulate them.

Comment: I was trying to open  them inside loop. As I opened them in for loop. Can you please suggest me how to do it. I have to do such operation on 21 such files.

Comment: sure you can open all the files in a `forloop` then use them. ie just have an empty list and append all the files in there. Then now manipulate the way you want

Comment: Are all the values string or numeric??

Comment: All of these are numeric.

Comment: Then you can use `pandas` which will read them as dataframes and you can easily add them:

Comment: Yea, Thats a good idea.I will try. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made the below code pretty verbose so you can see exactly what's going on. Feel free to modify to fit your use case.  This works with two text files assuming each contains comma separated values.

```
with open('file_1.txt', 'r') as file_1:
    file_1_data = file_1.readlines()

with open('file_2.txt', 'r') as file_2:
    file_2_data = file_2.readlines()

# Position of your column.  Zero is the first column.
position = 0

rows_file_1 = []
negative = False
for row in file_1_data:
    _ = []
    for item in row:
        if item is '-':
            negative = True
        elif item is ',' or item is ' ' or item is '\n':
            pass
        else:
            if negative is True:
                _.append(int(item) * -1)
                negative = False
            else:
                _.append(int(item))
    rows_file_1.append(_)

rows_file_2 = []
for row in file_2_data:
    _ = []
    for item in row:
        if item is '-':
            negative = True
        elif item is ',' or item is ' ' or item is '\n':
            pass
        else:
            if negative is True:
                _.append(int(item) * -1)
                negative = False
            else:
                _.append(int(item))
    rows_file_2.append(_)

print("Each inner array is a row. Values have been converted to integers.")
print(rows_file_1)
print(rows_file_2)

data_1 = [i[position] for i in rows_file_1]
data_2 = [i[position] for i in rows_file_2]

print()
print("Based upon the position, we've pulled out the column values your interested in.")
print(data_1)
print(data_2)

results = [i + ii for i, ii in zip(data_1, data_2)]

print()
print("Sum of each respective item in each file.")
print(results)
```

Comment: Thanks Eric I got some idea but still it doesn't work as I want. It add the first element of first column of file1 to all elements of first column in file2. I want to add first element of column 1 of  file1 to first element of column 1 of file2, second element to second and so on. Also, doesn't work when there is -ve sign.

Comment: @hemanta it shouldn’t be. They’re both using the same position variable.

Comment: I got the following error message when I make one value negative:Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "res.py", line 9, in <module>
    data_1 = [int(i[position]) for i in file_1_data]
  File "res.py", line 9, in <listcomp>
    data_1 = [int(i[position]) for i in file_1_data]
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '-'

Comment: It goes away if I remove that - sign.

Comment: Move the int casting in the list comp to i instead of where it is on i[position]

Comment: I did not get that, can you please make it more clear.

Comment: @hemanta updated to allow for null values, and I made the code very verbose so you can understand what's going on.  Please mark as accepted

Comment: Thank you so much. Helped me alot.